# ¿Cómo consigo el PID de un comando que lanzo en background?

Tags: bash, servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
uname -a
```

Hola, tengo por aquí una aplicación que me han encargado que se pueda gestionar como si fuera un servicio, el problema es que dicha aplicación (que está en proceso de desarrollo aun) se inicia de la siguiente manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
/usr/bin/node /home/pi/node-red-express/index.js &> /home/pi/node-red-express/debug_node_index.log &
```

Mi intención era empezar obteniendo el PID aprovechando la salida que me proporciona el simple hecho de iniciar en segundo plano con "&" al final...
Captura justo debajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Problema? pues que lo he intentado de varias maneras, pero no consigo capturar dicho resultado... Captura de ejemplo abajo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
echo $(/usr/bin/node /home/pi/node-red-express/index.js &> /home/pi/node-red-express/debug_node_index.log &)

a=$(/usr/bin/node /home/pi/node-red-express/index.js &> /home/pi/node-red-express/debug_node_index.log &)
echo $a
```

Sinceramente no tengo claro que se pueda hacer, aunque la lógica al principio me decía que si... He estado mirando, pero en un principio para que la gente cuando quiere recibir las salidas de otros comandos lo hace de esta manera... ¿Alguien me puede confirmar en un sentido o en otro?
¿Me podéis orientar al menos en cómo se haría?
¿Si creéis que me estoy complicando la vida podríais simplemente orientarme hacia otra solución?

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Aparte...
Mi intención es que una vez consiga el PID único del proceso pueda monitorizarlo enviando las señales pertinentes a partir de la comanda KILL con los parámetros correspondientes, pero eso ya es otra historia, de momento necesito una manera de obtener el PID de una manera inequívocamente, gracias.

Comment: por favor no muestres capturas de pantalla sino el código en texto, para que sea más usable por la gente que puede ayudarte. Dale a [edit] para hacer el cambio, ¡gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui, hola no lo he hecho porque entendia que no era necesario porque en un principio nadie tendria que copiar y pegar nada... Solo son capturas para mostrar que no me funciona, pero que vamos, que ahora mismo pongo justo debajo de las capturas el codigo, gracias.

Comment: claro, tienes razón en que los comandos en sí no son necesariamente copiables. De todos modos, las imágenes en general se reservan para casos en las que son _realmente_ necesarias, como una representación gráfica de una estructura de bases de datos o cosas así. Buena pregunta, por cierto!

Comment: @ferdoqui Vale entiendo, gracias, igualmente ya he puesto el codigo debajo, tendre en cuenta lo de las imagenes para el futuro, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas un comando en background te sale el valor de su PID automáticamente:

```
$ sleep 50 &
[1] 7454
```

Luego puedes buscarlo:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 7454
  502  7454  3973   0 10:09AM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 50
  502  7463  3973   0 10:09AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep 7454
```

Para guardar el número simplemente debes capturar el valor de `$!`:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 7482
$ echo $!
7482
```

Por tanto, la manera de guardar el PID es decir `comando &; pid=$!`:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 7485
$ pid=$!
$ echo "$pid"
7485
```

---

> Tengo por aquí una aplicación que me han encargado que se pueda gestionar como si fuera un servicio.

Lanzar un comando como lo estás haciendo actualmente es una manera, si bien es más recomendable ir a soluciones más estructurales, como sería *crear* un servicio. Me explico: cuando el servidor se levanta va y mira en `/etc/init.d/` qué servicios tiene que levantar. <sub>Hay unos cuantos directorios del tipo `rc2.d`, `rc3.d`... donde cada número corresponde a un punto del levantamiento del sistema. En nuestro caso, si queremos crear un servicio que se levante normalmente pondríamos un script en `rc5.d`.</sub> El script suele ser [del tipo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20361/40596):

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    # code to start app comes here 
    # example: daemon program_name &
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here 
    # example: killproc program_name
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here 
       # example: status program_name
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

y te permite entonces decir cosas como `service tuservicio start`, `service tuservicio stop`, así como definir si va a levantarse con la máquina mediante `chkconfig --add tuservicio` y luego definiendo los niveles con `chkconfig --level 2345 tuservicio on`. Con ello conseguirás que tu programa se levante automáticamente al levantar el servidor, así como te permitirá encenderlo y apagarlo mediante `service`.

Comment: Que grande, gracias me has salvado la vida con lo de "echo $!", encuanto a lo otro tienes razon, yo pensaba hacerlo con "systemctl", pero tu ejemplo me servira tambien.

¡Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: @ivan ¡qué bien! Mucho éxito y ya contarás qué tal te fue. Si con `systemctl` también te funciona, ¡adelante!

Comment: @fedorqui No sé si sea apropiado mencionar que tu propuesta de crear un servicio está orientada a sistemas que usan al buen *System V* (SysV) ya que no creo que sea la forma estándar, mas si en modo de retrocompatibilidad, de los que funcionan con *systemd*. Por ejemplo, hay algunas versiones de SO que no tienen `chkconfig` pero si `systemctl enable`.

Comment: @Marco oportunísimo comentario. Te animo a publicar otra respuesta indicando la forma más canónica o bien editar mi respuesta para corregir datos. Si quieres la pongo en modo wiki de comunidad.